# CNN image classification: accuracy values shakes greatly

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I try 2 class (dog/cat) classification with cnn.
But I found its graph of training is strange.
Why accuracy values shakes greatly? And is it correct training?

optimizer: adam
learning rate: 1e-4

network: https://gist.github.com/elect000/130acbdb0a3779910082593db4296254[image]

optimizer: adam
learning rate: 1e-6
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your learning rate is too high. 
When the learning rate is too high, the network takes large leaps when changing the weights, and this can cause it to overshoot the local minimum it's approaching.

Have a read of this article for a better description, and a nice diagram:
https://www.quora.com/In-an-artificial-neural-network-algorithm-what-happens-if-my-learning-rate-is-wrong-too-high-or-too-low

Comment: No. When I retry with learning-rate 1e-6, shaking is more greatly.

Comment: Interesting. That's a very bizarre graph you've gotten the second time around. I'd still suggest playing around with the learning rate a little bit. It's also possible your data set is too small to get any good results.